# Algebra Math help

Tags: polynomials

Andrew is putting a fringe with a width of $x$ an a border with a width of $y$ around a $24$-inch by $36$-inch tablecloth. Find an expression for the amount of material he will need for his project.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use this image to visualize it better.

[image]